# How to apply filters using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing an issue with elasticsearch using 'tire' gem. I have applied search on articles and want to apply a filter so that draft articles should not be visible in search. My code is as follows:

search_controller.rb

```
def articles_search
   @articles = Article.search(params)
end
```

article.rb

```
include Tire::Model::Search
include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  def self.search(params)
    if params[:query].present?
      tire.search(load: true) do
        query { string params[:query]} 
        filter :terms, :state => ['published']
      end
    else
      tire.search(load: true) do
        query { string "*#{params["term"]}*"}
        filter :terms, :state => ['published'] 
      end
    end 
  end
```

In articles table there is a column state I want only those articles with state 'published' but it's not working. It gives an empty result if I use filter :terms, :state => ['published'].

Comment: can anyone have any idea??